# Nativescript problem with height resize animation

Tags: ios, angular, animation, nativescript

Hey I've got weird problem with animated resizing 2 containers.
I wanted to get smooth height change. 
Make first 70% height, second 30%. After toggle first 30% and second 70%.
I don't know why there's yellow background visible 
Same behavior with angular animations.

Playground: 
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=V64lIV&v=1

TS:

```
public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.blueContainer.nativeElement.height = "30%";
    this.greenContainer.nativeElement.height = "70%";
}


public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.blueContainer.nativeElement.height = "30%";
    this.greenContainer.nativeElement.height = "70%";
}

blueBig() {
    this.resize = true;
    this.blueContainer.nativeElement.animate({
        height: "70%",
        duration: 800,
        curve: "linear"
    });

    this.greenContainer.nativeElement.animate({
        height: "30%",
        duration: 800,
        curve: "linear"
    });
}

blueSmall() {
    this.resize = false;
    this.blueContainer.nativeElement.animate({
        height: "30%",
        duration: 800,
        curve: "linear"
    });

    this.greenContainer.nativeElement.animate({
        height: "70%",
        duration: 800,
        curve: "linear"
    });
}
```

XML:

```
<GridLayout
        rows="*, auto"
        backgroundColor="yellow"
        height="100%"
        width="100%">

    <StackLayout row="0"
                 backgroundColor="green"
                 #greenContainer></StackLayout>

    <StackLayout row="1"
                 backgroundColor="blue"
                 (tap)="resize ? blueSmall() : blueBig()"
                 #blueContainer></StackLayout>

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: It looks OK on  Android 9 - no yellow background showing

Comment: I tried on Android 8.1, it looks good to me too. Is it a iOS specific issue @romanto?

Comment: Looks like its iOS issue. By the looks of it, while animating the vertical alignment of the component in its container moves to center, @NickIliev could be a bug?

Comment: yes, i'm using ios... ;(

Comment: @Romanto were you able to fix this?